# Does jqgrid support row height so i can get multi lines showing in one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a few columns that are very long and i want to show all of the content so i want to setup jqgrid to have the height of each row able to show multiple lines of text in one cell which word wraps

is this possible

Comment: Does IE 6 support this?

Thanks.
Archan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following bit of CSS will enable word wrap:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
  white-space: normal !important;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  padding-top:2px;
}
```

See [this link](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2009/12/03/jqgrid-textword-wrapping/) for more information.

Comment: Its doesn't seem to work on firefox for me, but it does on IE..any ideas why?

Comment: Not offhand. If possible, I suggest posting a link to a jsfiddle that can reproduce the problem. That way myself or others can see the actual problem you are running into...

Comment: where would we put that css?  in the JqGrid css file?

Comment: You could but it would be better to include it in one of your own CSS files. That way when you upgrade jqGrid you don't have to remember to replace this code.